# java Cannot delete file, being used by another process

Tags: java, delete-file

I have this code

```
 import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    try {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(SHA1_LINK), new File("SHA1.txt"));
        if(!sameSha1()) {
            System.out.println("sha diferentes");
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(LINK), new File(PROG));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Internet is off");
    }
    //delete SHA1 file
    Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("SHA1.txt"));
```

and when I execute it it says

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (in sun.nio.fs.WindowsException)

In the `sameSha1()` I have this:

```
String sha1Txt = new Scanner(new File("SHA1.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

I want to delete the file 'SHA1.txt'. How can I do this?

Comment: what else is using this file, keeping it open?

Comment: Can you provide sameSha1 implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess with `sameSha1` you open `SHA1.txt` to read it and you forget to close it.

EDIT:

From your comment you contain the following line in `sameSha1`:

```
String sha1Txt = new Scanner(new File("SHA1.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

So you create a scanner instance but you don't explicitly close it. You should do something like that:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("SHA1.txt"));
try {
    String sha1Txt = s.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    ...
    return result;
}
finally {
    s.close();
}
```

Or as @HuStmpHrrr suggests in Java 7:

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("SHA1.txt"))) {
    String sha1Txt = s.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you. In the sameSha1 I have this: `String sha1Txt = new Scanner(new File("SHA1.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();`. How do I close it?

Comment: you assign new Scanner(...) in a variable s and before you return you call `s.close()`

Comment: you use  `try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("SHA1.txt")))` to close the file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If it's being used by another process, I'm guessing some other program has that text file open. Try closing the other program.

Comment: All the programs are closed except the IDE that I use, and it doesn't have the SHA1.txt file open

Comment: @dan_san_1, something **is** holding a lock on it for sure: the exception tell as much. Use some tool to find out what is doing this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Or go to the directory where it is saved, list hidden files and delete the lock yourself. In linux that's ls -a to show the files, and remove the one that has the ~. Not sure if it's the same for Windows, but you can show hidden files under folder properties and see if you can find the .lock file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to auto-close file resource when it's used, something like this :

```
Path tempFilePath = fileUtil.createTempFile( uploadedInputStream, fileDetail.getFileName() );
File tempFile = tempFilePath.toFile();

try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream( tempFile )) {
    uploadDocument( fileTypeId, description, is );
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.debug( e );
}

Files.deleteIfExists( tempFilePath );
```